# Question about meaning of the phrase "unless otherwise"

Tags: sentence-meaning, legalese

> The maximum speed limit on most California highways is 65 mph. You may drive 70 mph where posted. **Unless** **otherwise** posted, the maximum speed limit is 55 mph on two-lane undivided highways and for vehicles towing trailers.Other speed limit signs are posted for the type of roads and traffic in each area. All speed limits are based on ideal driving conditions. Construction zones usually have reduced speed zones.

My perception is that the maximum speed limit is 55 mph on two-lane undivided highways. Is this correct?

Could you simplify the term ***unless otherwise*** in simple English?

Comment: For me, it is a redundancy. It is unnecessary repetition.

Comment: unless otherwise means 'if nothing else'

Comment: @AlelignAschaleWudie - It's not a redundancy; you couldn't use _otherwise_ by itself, and using _unless_ by itself would produce an awkward sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right, that is what it means.

**Unless** means "if not". **Otherwise** means "in another way, differently". So **unless otherwise posted** will mean "if nothing else is posted", "if nothing else is indicated", "if there are no other signs".

Other examples:

- *The document has a validity of 5 years, unless otherwise stated.*
- *Residents are not to leave the premises unless otherwise instructed.*

Answer (score 0):

This means that *unless a sign indicates a different speed limit*, the speed limit is 55mph.

**Unless otherwise** means 'unless something different is indicated'.